# Any concrete, real life example of Peirce's Law?

Tags: truth, philosophy-of-logic

What would be a real life, concrete example of Peirce's Law?

> ((p → q) → p) → p

There is a Wikipedia article on it, if you are unfamiliar with it:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce's_law

There is also on Wikipedia of a discussion about giving a concrete example, which went nowhere:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Peirce's_law

Peirce gave a short explanation of the formula:

> ((x → y) → x) → x. This is hardly axiomatical. That it is true appears as follows. It can only be false by the final consequent x being false while its antecedent (x → y) → x is true. If this is true, either its consequent, x, is true, when the whole formula would be true, or its antecedent x → y is false. But in the last case the antecedent of x → y, that is x, must be true.
> https://www.jstor.org/stable/2369451?seq=10#metadata_info_tab_contents

Peirce's Law is a rather simple formula and it is proved valid in mathematical logic--through a Natural Deduction proof or using a truth table--so it should be easy to a give concrete, real life example of it.

Peirce's Law, although a true logical truth, seems essentially nonsensical, but maybe someone knows how to bring zombies back to life?

Comment: For (P →Q) → P:"If us working on improving yields implied that our product would be better in 6 months, then we would work on improving yields". [John Baez recommends](https://twitter.com/johncarlosbaez/status/1069836589004541953) getting from this to ((P →Q) → P) → P by cases with P true and P false considered separately. The latter case appeals to *ex falso quodlibet*:"We're not doing it, which means the implication is technically true, which means we are doing it".

Comment: @Conifold *If p is false, then p is true* doesn't make for a real life example.Technically true in mathematical logic if p is true, but not true in real life.

Comment: "If p is false, then p is true" is not valid in mathematical logic either. The form used is "if p false implies any q then p is true", i.e. a version of *ex falso quodlibet*. Few find EFQ intuitive so one should not expect more from Peirce's law. Not to mention that people are generally bad at intuitively interpreting even two nested implications, let alone three, regardless of logic used or Peirce's law.

Comment: If it is raining when if it is raining, then it is cloudy, then it is raining.

Comment: Peirce's law is "similar" to Modus Ponens. MP "defines" the condition for asserting the *consequent*: we can assert **Q** when "if **P**, then **Q** and **Q**" hold. The same for Peirce's law regarding the *antecedent*: we can assert **P** when "**P** if, if **P**, then **Q**" hold.

Comment: By "real life example" do you mean an example where it's applied in "real life" math reasoning, or in some informal "real life" logic context? (Also keep in mind that there's an infinite amount of tautologies in "classical logic" LK, most of which are almost certainly never applied directly to any "real life" problem by any definition of that, be it "real life" mathematical proofs or informal logic). Peirce's law added to intuitionistic logic gives all of LK.

Comment: @Fizz 1. "*Real life, concrete example*" seems clear enough. See a dictionary if you are uncertain about the vocabulary. 2. "classical logic", "intuitionistic logic" etc. If you can come up with a real-life example, just make sure you explain how you arrived at it.

Comment: People do mathematics in real life and they also do informal logic in real life. (As Wikipedia's article on it explains) Peirce's law is useful/interesting because one can express the law of excluded middle with it without having any connective besides implication in the logic (fragment). In virtually all parts of "real life" thinking one uses disjunctions as well, so Peirce's law in itself isn't that interesting of a substitute for LEM. Assuming a deduction theorem, Peirce's law is equivalent with x |- x, x, y where the right-hand side of the sequent is read disjunctively.

Comment: Besides, if you object to Peirce's law (on the ground of lack of "real life" example), why not object to ((x → y) → z) → ((x → y) → (x → z)) (what Wikipedia [calls THEN-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Hilbert-style_calculus)), which is actually taken as an axiom of many logical calculi (including classical and intuitionistic one). The moral of this story is (simply) that Hilbert style axiomatization, which uses only MP as its "structural" rule, "creates"/necessitates many "hairy" axioms to compensate... (Obviously, THEN-2 is also provable e.g. in a Gentzen-style LK.)

Comment: @Fizz "*if you object to Peirce's law *" Sorry, I'm not too interested in the quirks of mathematical logic. Both Pierce's Law and (A → B) → C ⊢ (A → B) → (A → C) are true implications, irrespective of what mathematical logic may happen to say. See also my edit at the end of my question, to give some context.

Comment: Why was this question closed? It is a perfectly good question with already three answers. It shows something very interesting, namely that people have difficulty finding concrete examples to an implication even though it is true and quite straightforward. Aren't you interested in the logic of human deductive reasoning? This is supposed to be a website about philosophy but it has been highjacked by mathematicians. How many of my questions have been closed for always the same spurious reasons? Well, nearly all.

Answer (score 1):

A misleading feature I observe in many textbooks on logic is that they restrict translations to and from natural language to a few strict patterns, upshot of which is a habit of interpretations bereft of the huge power of **informal semantics**, which, however, mathematicians freely enjoy (I have always thought that it would be very nice if the English language had a verb "enmean," in analogy to "enable," beside "interpret", for those cases we bring the phenomena naturally that have no meaning to being meaningful). Hence, one has actually the freedom, for example, to translate 'α → β' as "whenever α obtains, β obtains as well," or "on the condition that α, β occurs," etc. according to the context. Also, it is not required to form one long sentence as a translation of a compound proposition.

Returning to Peirce's law ((α → β) → α) → α with these remarks in mind, we may take α → β as "whenever we have α, we have β" and '(α → β) → α' as "we have α on the condition that whenever we have α, we have β." Thus, we can compose such a sentence:

> If we have the right to that land on the condition that whenever we
> have the right [to that land], others [also] have the right to it,
> then we [do] have *that right*.

Notice that, though we have admitted others also have the right whenever we have, we are disinterested in the others' right (sure, we could exchange us and them). In any way, the resultant sentence would *necessarily* pick out α, and β would be excluded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The method to arrive at your example seems good to me, but the example itself seems wrong. The semantics of "to have the right to that land" clearly suggests that the right of someone is exclusive of other people's rights, which makes α → β false in your example. Is that a deliberate choice on your part? Can you explain?

Comment: @Speakpigeon Of course α → β can be false and Peirce's law still holds. The problem is that in natural language unrelated statements *seem* false (or at least weird) when tied together by logical connectives. As I said in a comment (assuming deduction theorem and contraction) Pierce's law is equivalent to stating α |- α, β, i.e. "If we have the right to land then we have that right or others do" seems "relevant-istic" but "If we have the right to land then we either have that right or the moon is made of blue cheese" is just as true in LK but sounds more weird. [continues]

Comment: If you want the "least implausible" example from a natural language perspective, take  α = β which results in sentence(s) that might make good stand-up comedy due to their repetition and obviousness. "If I have a dog then I have a dog or I surely have one". (You can obviously chain that one ad nauseam.)

Comment: @Fizz 1. "*The problem is that in natural language unrelated statements seem false*" Sure, but this shouldn't stop anyone who understand that Pierce's Law is true from providing a concrete example of it. The question of irrelevance is irrelevant here. - 2. "*If I have a dog then I have a dog or I surely have one*" This would be an example for ((p → p) → p) → p, not for ((p → q) → p) → p.

Comment: @ It's an instance of both obviously. It's not a proper (non-degenerate) instance on the latter.

Comment: @Fizz I didn't talk of "instance". It is not a proper concrete example of Pierce's Law.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Here's another example: "If the condition that Argentina has the right to claim territory on Antarctica only if so-and-so countries have this right suffices Argentina to have it [the mentioned right], then she has it." We can take 'so-and-so countries' as 'all the countries' (including Argentina) or 'other countries' (excluding Argentina); either one is fine. It may be helpful to view Peirce's law as a diagrammatic imagery such as that of a positive feedback loop.

Comment: @TankutBeygu That's not ((p → q) → p) → p but ((q → p) → p) → p.

Comment: @Speakpigeon 'only if' is an expression of logical jargon to denote the necessary condition: In the material implication p → q, p is a sufficient condition for q and q is a necessary condition for p. Hence, an alternative way to translate the implication.

Comment: "we have α on the condition that whenever we have α, we have β." This verbal summary seems misleading since (α → β) → α is true in the case that (α → β) is *false* but α is true.

Comment: @Hypnosifl any atomic proposition can be false; that's why material implication strikes many people as paradoxical. A heuristic to make sense of propositional formulas in natural language is to assign truth to all the simple (atomic) propositions, take this interpretation as central and comment on the other valuations with reference to it. Propositional formulas are, so to say, skeletons: One has to flesh them out according to the context.

Comment: @TankutBeygu 1. "*only if*" Ok, my bad. - 2. You still haven explained. The semantics of "to have the right to that land" clearly suggests that the right of someone is exclusive of other people's rights, which makes α → β false in your example. Similarly, the fact that Argentina has a right does not imply that any other country has the same right. I am asking for a real-life example.

Comment: "take this interpretation as central and comment on the other valuations with reference to it" OK, but you didn't do the latter in your answer, and the ordinary english interpretation of "we have β on the condition that α" would be that if you don't have α, you won't have β (e.g., "you can have dessert on the condition that you eat your vegetables"), which does not match with the logical meaning of α → β. So I would say that your translation into English is misleading if you don't explicitly spell out whatever you mean by "other valuations", which would be complicated for a nested statement.

Comment: @Hypnosifl briefly try a narrative: Suppose α represents Argentina's claim and β internationally sought-after agreement on the issue. By international law, β is a necessary condition for α. Both α and β obtain, no conflict occurs and Peirce's law is done. Suppose β does not obtain, however, Argentina breaches the norms, say, by a military fait accompli, etc. and wins out her claim: done. Suppose an agreement is reached, but Argentina is not interested in such a claim: done. Lastly, there is neither Argentina's claim nor an agreement: done. For sure, the law imposes a specific worldview.

Comment: @TankutBeygu - Your narrative doesn't match the truth table for material implication--I don't know if the narrative is meant to illustrate α → β or β → α, but either way, you included a case where β is false and α is true ('Suppose β does not obtain, however, Argentina breaches the norms, say, by a military fait accompli, etc. and wins out her claim') and one where α is false and β is true ('Suppose an agreement is reached, but Argentina is not interested in such a claim'). If the antecedent of a material condition is true, the consequent must be true for the material conditional to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Pierce's law works on the peculiarity of the truth table of implication, in which an implication is only *false* when the antecedent is *true* and the consequent is *false*. Implication is always *true* otherwise. We can show Pierce's law through *reductio ad absurdum*:

1. For Pierce's law to be false, **((P → Q) → P)** must be *true* and
   **P** *false*
2. If **P** is *false* (p1), **(P → Q)** must be *true* in all cases.
3. If **(P → Q)** is necessarily *true* (p2) and **P** is *false* (p1), then **((P → Q) → P)** is *false*
4. However, if **((P → Q) → P)** is necessarily *false* (p3), and **P** is false (p1), then **(((P → Q) → P) → P)** is *true*, contradicting the premise we made in p1

**P** must be *true*, because asserting that it is *false* leads to contradiction.

What Pierce's law says in (somewhat) plain English is that if we ask whether "(B is contingent on A) is contingent on the existence of A", then that question itself implies the (logical) existence of A. For a real world example, let's consider lambs and sheep:

1. The existence of sheep (P) implies the existence of lambs (Q).

   - **(P → Q)**: This could be *true* or *false*: true in the 'natural' mode of ovine reproduction; false if we are (say) cloning lambs out of base genetic material or some such.
2. The idea that the existence of sheep implies the existence of lambs implies sheep exist.

   - **((P → Q) → P)**: This too could be *true* or *false*. In the case that sheep exist this is always true (existing sheep may or may not imply lambs, but they still exist). In the case that sheep *do not* exist, this is always false (the terms always evaluate to **T → F**, whether or not lambs exist). In essence, this assertion says that if sheep do (or do not) exist, they do (or do not) exist whether or not they have a relationship to lambs. Lambs become irrelevant to the discussion.
3. Asking whether point #2 implies the existence of sheep de-evolves to an implicative tautology: effectively it says that the existence of sheep implies the existence of sheep.

   - **((P → Q) → P) → P**: This can only be *true*, though that is hardly obvious from the formulation. The only way for it to be false is to construct a scenario in which the existence of sheep implies their non-existence (a kind of Schrödinger's sheep, if you will...).

I hope that clarifies things, instead of confusing them further.

Comment: "*Pierce's law works on the peculiarity of the truth table of implication, in which an implication is only false when the antecedent is true and the consequent is false*" No. Pierce's Law is a true implication. Pierce himself proved that. 2. "*The only way for it to be false*" There is no way for a true implication to be false.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: the phrase 'true implication' seems to have a specific meaning for you. Could you explain?

Comment: Nothing special. An implication which is true, in the ordinary sense of these words. Any proposition which is true is not false.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: Then I'm not clear on why you're objecting to my analysis. Do you see something wrong in those first four bullet points?

Comment: I didn't object to that but if you want to know, point 2 and 4 is mathematical logic nonsense. Sorry you learned that stuff. However, this is independent of my initial comment, which seems clear enough and in no need of elaboration.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: Pierce's law is a statement of **logic**. Saying that Pierce's law is 'true' (in the logical sense) and then poo-pooing the logical derivation as 'nonsense' is odd, to say the least. If you're going to dispute the rules of logic, then why are you asking about Pierce's law in the first place?

Comment: "*poo-pooing the logical derivation*" What you proposed in your answer is not logical derivation. It is *mathematical logic* derivation, which is why it is nonsense. "* If you're going to dispute the rules of logic*" I don't I dispute the relevance of mathematical logic. Mathematical logic is crap but Pierce's Law is all good.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: I"m sorry, but that's nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with translating material conditionals into english is that they often mislead since if-then statements in English normally have a range of meanings that go beyond the material conditional (see the [indicative condition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/conditionals/)). To avoid these kinds of confusions, it helps to keep in mind that in logic the material condition "A -> B" is completely equivalent in meaning to the statement "~A or B" (this is one of the rules of 'conditional exchange', see p. 302 of [this chapter on truth-functional logic](https://www.pearsonhighered.com/assets/samplechapter/0/3/2/1/0321108825.pdf)). So by the same rule "(p -> q) -> p" must be equivalent to "~(p -> q) or p", which is equivalent to "~(~p or q) or p", and then you can use one of de Morgan's laws (see p. 300 of the book chapter above) to show this is equivalent to "(p and ~q) or p". And regardless of whether one or both sides of that last "or" statement is true, p would have to be true either way, so it should be clear enough conceptually why "(p and ~q) or p" -> p is tautologically true, since it's logically impossible you could have a situation where "(p and ~q) or p" is true but p is false.

Since it's tautologically true, you can put any claim you want in for p and q to give a concrete example of why it's true. For example, say p = "the sky is blue" and q = "rabbits are herbivores" so that ~q = "rabbits are not herbivores". Then you could write it like this:

(the sky is blue AND rabbits are not herbivores) OR (the sky is blue) logically implies (the sky is blue).

Comment: The question is "*What would be **a real life**, **concrete example** of Peirce's Law?*". Your answer completely fails to address this question.

Comment: @Speakpigeon - How are "the moon is made of green cheese" and "rabbits are carnivorous" not concrete statements? Are you bothered by the fact that they are not *true* in real life? But it's a tautology, so its validity doesn't depend on whether the concrete statements are true or false. As an analogy, if there was a question asking for a "real life, concrete example" of the tautology "A -> A", would you accept "(the sky is blue) -> (the sky is blue)" but reject "(the sky is green) -> (the sky is green)"? Or would you accept both, or reject both?

Comment: We seem to disagree about what is real life.

Comment: Would you be willing to answer my questions above to clarify what your criteria for "real life" is? Specifically, is it just the requirement that the propositions be true rather than false in the real world (if so I'd be happy to modify my answer so that it would involve only those types of propositions), and would you consider either of the propositions I substituted for A in the tautology A->A to qualify as "concrete, real life examples" of A->A?

Comment: More generally do you think it *is* possible to have a concrete, real life example for A->A, or do you think that differs in some important way from Pierce's law such that the request for concrete, real life examples makes sense for Pierce's law but not for A->A? Hopefully you would agree that both are tautologies which must be true for any arbitrary proposition you substitute in, so it's not like a situation of someone requesting an example of propositions that satisfy a non-tautologous statement like "(A or B) -> C", where only some particular choices of propositions would work.

Comment: "***real life** n a. actual human life, as lived by real people, esp contrasted with the lives of fictional or fantasy characters: miracles don't happen in real life.*"

Comment: So you aren't willing to answer the specific questions I asked above? I asked them because I have no idea whether "real life" for you is purely a characteristic of the individual propositions, or whether you're talking about some more holistic sense that the particular *choice* of concrete/real-life propositions has to provide some non-trivial insight that allows you to "make sense" of the statement in a new way, so that something like (the sky is blue) -> (the sky is blue) wouldn't qualify since putting "the sky is blue" into A->A doesn't give any new insight.

Comment: In case it is just a matter of the individual propositions being concrete and true in real life, I edited my answer so that the propositions I used actually were both. But if this isn't satisfying, again I would ask that you please answer my questions above to clarify what it is you find unsatisfying.

Comment: 1. "*So you aren't willing to answer the specific questions I asked above?*" I provided the best answer there is, viz. a dictionary definition of "real life". If this is not enough for you, then how could you possibly understand anything anyone says or writes, including logic textbooks? 2. "*I edited my answer*" I didn't ask an example for "~A or B". I asked an example for ((p → q) → p) → p. And if your example is p = "the sky is blue" and q = "rabbits are not herbivores", then this isn't a real-life example since q is false. Why can't we have a real-life example?

Comment: The dictionary definition doesn't tell me whether you would consider "the sky is blue implies the sky is blue" is a real-life example, the atomic propositions are real-life truths but the statement as a whole is non-empirical so it doesn't express a fact one would learn from any real-life experience, nor does it have any real-life relevance. So could you please just tell me "yes" or "no" in response to my question about whether you would call that a "real life example" of A->A? Also, since my answer used ~q rather than q I thought you might prefer ~q be true, but I will change it.

Comment: But if "the sky is blue implies the sky is blue" wasn't a real-life example of A → A, nothing would. So, yes, it is. I didn't ask for real-life *arguments*. I asked for real-life examples, and then for real life-example of Pierce's Law, which is itself probably never used in real life outside formal logic.

Comment: That being said, assuming that p = "the sky is blue" and q = "rabbits are herbivores" doesn't work, as you should be able to realise by yourself. Take your time, and if you ever understand why, I'd be pleased to hear from you. I suspect you won't be able to understand as you seem keen on using the material implication.

Comment: "you won't be able to understand as you seem keen on using the material implication" Are you saying you want answers that *don't* assume material implication? If so this should be specified in the question, I think all the answers so far have assumed it is. And if you're not using material implication but some different notion of implication, it wouldn't necessarily be a tautology--do you agree? In that case, there might be certain combinations of propositions that would satisfy it while others would not, so your question about a "real life example" that would satisfy it might make more sense.

Comment: 1. "*answers that don't assume material implication?*" All answers so far rely on the MI and all are wrong but this is your choice. If you use the MI and you find a good answer, it will still be one good answer. - 2. "*some different notion of implication, it wouldn't necessarily be a tautology*" I'm using the logic of human deductive reasoning. Seems enough. - 3. The notion of tautology comes with MI. - 4. "*there might be certain combinations of propositions*" Pierce's Law is a true implication, so I'm sure there are real-life instances of it.

Comment: But the "logic of human deductive reasoning" tends to involve different notions of "implication" than material implication, as discussed in the [SEP indicative conditionals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/conditionals/) article--for example, many if-then statements in ordinary speech are assertions about what conclusions *would* follow in a possible world where the antecedent was true, more like a statement from modal logic than the material conditional. So with some other definition of "→" there is no reason to think "((p → q) → p) → p" would be true for all p's and q's--do you disagree?

Comment: Also there is the point that Peirce himself, and all the logicians who cite "Peice's law", are assuming "→" represents the material conditional--if you want to ask about the statement "((p implies q) implies p) implies p" using a different definition of "implies", it's misleading to call this Peirce's law, just like one couldn't call F=ma "Newton's second law" if one redefined the meaning of the symbol "a".

Comment: Your reasoning is wrong but, oops, sorry, the question has been closed.

Comment: The only statement I made in my last comment that wasn't just about terminology was *'with some other definition of "→" there is no reason to think "((p → q) → p) → p" would be true for all p's and q's'*. If you disagree with that, perhaps you should start a new question asking if ((p → q) → p) → p would still be guaranteed to hold even if → is just interpreted as any type of reasoned deduction rather than as a material conditional; I could give you an example where p and q represent some hypothetical laws and → represents a legal implication, such ((p → q) → p) → p doesn't work.

Comment: "*legal implication*" A new kind of implication? If you simply mean "logical implication" applied to legal matters, and if you were right that Pierce's Law "*doesn't work*", you would have a counterexample to it and I don't believe that possible. Pierce's Law is as secure as the modus ponens.

Comment: Again, Pierce's law is *defined* in terms of material implication, if you try to say *((p implies q) implies p) implies p)* using a notion of "implies" that differs in any way from material implication, as you seemed to want to do, then one can find cases where that statement (which is *not* Pierce's law if 'implies' is taken to mean anything other than material implication) is false. I was suggesting that using a particular legal notion of "implies" that is different from material implication, I could show a case where that statement is false--do you think that's impossible?

Comment: 1. "*Pierce's law is defined in terms of material implication*" No, Pierce's Law was defined by Pierce himself and proven by him through a reasoning in natural language, relying therefore on conditionals, not on the material implication..- 2. There is just one kind of logical implication. Pierce's Law is a true logical implication, in the same sense as the modus ponens or any other logical truth is a true logical implication. - 3."*one can find cases where that statement is false*" No. - 4.Please explain your "particular legal notion of "implies"?

Comment: "proven by him through a reasoning in natural language" What's your source for that claim? Wikipedia says that he presented the law "as an axiom in his first axiomatisation of propositional logic", and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.2429.pdf indicates that Peirce wrote down a truth table for his version of the conditional that was identical to the one later used to define material implication. "There is just one kind of logical implication" Not true, for example in modal logic there is "strict implication" discussed at https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-1713-7_4

Comment: And “implication” in natural language can be associated with all sorts of other meanings as discussed in the [indicative conditional](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/conditionals/) article. And if you think there is just one kind of logical implication, then you should say that all statements of logical implication involve the same truth table as material implication (unless you think logicians including Peirce chose the wrong truth table)—so why did you say before “you won't be able to understand as you seem keen on using the material implication”?

Comment: When I mentioned “legal implication” I was thinking of if-then statements of legality where it’s implicitly understood in natural language that an “if and only if” condition is meant, like “if John is 21 or over, then that implies John can legally drink”. In natural language I think everyone would understand that if the antecedent is false (John is under 21) than the consequent must be false as well (John cannot legally drink), but a material conditional is deemed true when the antecedent is false but the consequent is true.

Comment: "*Peirce wrote down a truth table*" Good for him, but he also provided a natural language justification. There is a reason that mathematicians adopted the material implication. Essentially, it was an easy fit. Too easy to resist.

Comment: "*in modal logic there is ''strict implication''*" Fallacious. It is not because some self-described expert call something an implication that it is an implication. If there were different implications, we could not possibly understand each other without asking which implication is meant. You think natural selection decided different implications would be useful to us?

Comment: "Good for him, but he also provided a natural language justification." Where did he do that? Do you have a link or book reference? And are you claiming that his supposed natural language justification was correct but his truth table was wrong? "If there were different implications, we could not possibly understand each other without asking which implication is meant." Nonsense, we can understand based on context, like my age-of-drinking example. Do you claim that Peirce's law would work even if we interpreted implication as an "if and only if, then" as in that example?

Comment: Search "This is hardly axiomatical" if you don't already know it. For example:: "*IF it is true, (THEN) either its consequent, A, is true, when the whole formula would be true, or its antecedent A ⊃ B is false*"

Comment: That argument quoted on the Peirce's law wiki page clearly depends on a truth table where A->B can only be false if the antecedent A is true and consequent B is false, but where the statement is true in all other cases (note his comment *It can only be false by the final consequent x being false while its antecedent (x → y) → x is true*). And isn't your position that the truth table of the material conditional doesn't accurately capture the logic of implicational statements in natural language? What combos of truth values for A and B do *you* think are needed to make "A implies B" true?

Comment: I couldn't possibly know what Peirce had in mind but his reasoning doesn't explicitly rely on the material implication. So, you interpret it as you please, and so do I.

Comment: The term "material implication" didn't exist yet AFAIK, but he explicitly relies on the assumption that an implication is only false if the antecedent is true and the consequent false, while it would be true in every other case. Logically this is all that "material implication" means, it has nothing else in its definition. Do you agree with Peirce that an implication is only false if the antecedent is true and the consequent false, yes or no? If no, what combinations of truth values for the antecedent and consequent do *you* think make an implication true or false?

Comment: The question is closed.

Comment: That didn't stop you from returning to the comments here to initiate further discussion over the last couple days. But if the question being closed is your main reason for not answering my question about how you think the truth-values of antecedent A and consequent B relate to the truth-value of "A implies B", I could repeat the question in a comment on your answer [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/75659/10780) where you asserted the material conditional doesn't accurately capture the logical meaning of conditionals in natural language. Would you be willing to answer in that case?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not teaching logic.

Comment: I'm not asking you to "teach" me about any standard logical ideas, I'm asking you to answer some basic questions about your own apparent claim that all modern logicians including Peirce are *wrong* to use material implication. & I'm also not asking for any detailed explanation of your ideas, just a couple simple true/false questions: 1. Is "A implies B" true or false when A is false but B is true? 2. Is "A implies B" true or false when both A and B are individually false? (I assume you'd agree with material implication that it's true when A and B are true, and false when A is true/B is false)